# ssh for df -h using python to display selected information only

Tags: python, ssh

I am using python to view disk space with the following code:

```
import subprocess
ret = subprocess.call(["ssh", "hostname", "df -h"]);#hostname is server info
```

but this code shows all the information. I want to display only first line.

Comment: @vefthym thank you for your review, i am expecting some solution too

Comment: Will you please mention what output u are getting?

Comment: i just want to print the first line of the result.

Comment: @mguijarr i got this error on your suggestion 

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @santosh_new: I just sent an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the standard output of the sub-process, then you can read
the first line:

```
sub_process=subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "hostname", "df -h"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_file=sub_process.stdout
first_line=stdout_file.readline()
```